# Python bindings for vlc don't working propetly

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

If i jump to miliseconds, vlc jump to miliseconds + 190

```
    # VLC player controls
    self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()


    # OpenFile
    self.OnStop(None)
    # Creation
    self.Media = self.Instance.media_new(unicode("10min.mp4"))
    self.player.set_media(self.Media)
    # Report the title of the file chosen


    # set the window id where to render VLC's video output
    self.player.set_hwnd(self.videopanel.GetHandle())


   self.player.set_time(200)
```

It jumps to 390 etc, so i made simple walkaround: 
    self.player.set_time(time - 190)

but if time is < 190 i have exception....
Somebody had this problem with vlc bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess VLC may jump between key frames only for specific media types.

Comment: this is h.264. After 190 ms i can jump to each frame

Answer (score 0):

It's not python bindings who don't work properly but VLC, I don't know why, but is VLC who is jumping those extra 190ms.
You can download some plugins that allow yo to see the ms, the one I'm using i go to the fourth second, then ask the plugin to get the time and it gives 4.190...